# Multiline textbox won't move cursor to the end

Tags: c#, scroll, visual-studio-2015, textbox

I have a multiline textbox which I fill with text (on form load) from a txt file. I'm trying to move the vertical scroll to the bottom (since there are quite a few lines) in any possible way.

I've tried appending text, using ScrollToCaret, changing the selection and several other ways I found, but non of them are working.

I've tried moving everything I found to the textChanged event and placing it right after I filled the textbox, but its still not scrolling to the bottom.

Whenever I use anything I found that could possibly work, the position is still at the beginning of the textbox's text.

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance

This is the code I'm using to add the text to the textbox

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{

    txtLog.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(path));
    File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

}
```

Comment: `box.SelectionStart = box.Text.Length;` ?

Comment: tried that one too. Sorry that I couldn't mention everything I tried, but I couldn't remember everything

Comment: So what does happen when you use it?  Perhaps show the code where you add the text ...

Comment: Can you add some of your code

Comment: Maybe try [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've not yet resorted to a RichTextBox, but wouldn't it have the same problem as a normal textbox?

Comment: @GokusGString don't know. That's not many changes in code, but it's worth to check.

Comment: Changed it to a RichTextBox and it works perfectly..So it's only with a normal textbox that everything I tried doesn't work

Comment: @GokusGString I added my answer bellow, so please upvote, and mark as resolved, when it really works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing TextBox to [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) should resolve Your problem.

Comment: Don't know why it wouldn't work with a normal textbox but this worked. Thanks everyone =)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your code.
And make sure to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` at the top of your code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private const int WM_VSCROLL = 277;
        private const int SB_PAGEBOTTOM = 7;

        public static void ScrollToBottom(TextBox textBox)
        {
            SendMessage(textBox.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGEBOTTOM, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
```

And change your code to this

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{

    txtLog.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(path));
    ScrollToBottom(txtLog);
    File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

}
```

Comment: Just rechecked its a regular textbox set to be multiline

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a regular TextBox the following should work:

```
txtLog.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(path));
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(txtLog.ScrollToEnd, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```